# can't install expo-cli in the new win 10 1903

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo

I installed node js 13.2 and I even tried installing yarn.
In visual studio installer I ticked C++ build tools and node js msbuild.
Yet whenever I install expo-cli globally I get these error:

```
sharp.cc
  utilities.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
C:\Users\uPanda\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\sharp\src\stats.cc(130,1): error C2661: 'v8::Obj
ect::Set': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments [C:\Users\uPanda\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_mod
ules\sharp\build\sharp.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\uPanda\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v13.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
```

And this at the end:

```
> envsub@3.1.0 postinstall C:\Users\uPanda\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\envsub
> test -d .git && cp gitHookPrePush.sh .git/hooks/pre-push || true

'test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'true' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: sharp@0.22.1 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\sharp):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: sharp@0.22.1 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! envsub@3.1.0 postinstall: `test -d .git && cp gitHookPrePush.sh .git/hooks/pre-push || true`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the envsub@3.1.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\uPanda\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-01T12_34_33_996Z-debug.log

C:\Windows\system32>expo
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957
    throw err;
    ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, the answer is very simple :

> Never Run `npm` With Administrator Rights

Comment: Can you provide insight into why that is important? @UPanda

Comment: @Mallesbixie Actually if you run npm with admin rights, it can't identify the user and it automatically tries to create `node_modules` in a folder somewhere in system32, well that's in the old versions of node, it has been fixed now

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
OS: Win 10.
As I understood it's connected with envsub@3.1.0
The problem was fixed in new version of envsub but expo-cli still uses 3.1.0

P.S.

3.5.0 works

```
npm install -g expo-cli@3.5.0
```

Comment: Thanks It's a relief to know that the problem is not from me !

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:
`expo init`
follow the prompt.
You can either chose to install with Yarn or npm.
It works for me.